How can I create a row of single-character text boxes and have the cursor automatically advance as the user types?
I'm making an app for mobile automotive repair for my own personal use. In my customer information section, I have a pane for entering vehicle information. In that vehicle information, I want to include the seventeen digit VIN of the vehicle.
In my label display (a different area of the app), I want the seventeen-digit VIN to be parsed so I can quickly identify the eighth character, and the last eight characters. The eighth is the engine code. The last eight are what the dealerships use when they look up parts.
It seems to me that it would be simpler to concatenate seventeen separate characters and add spaces where I want them than it would be to take a seventeen digit string and parse it.
So, I decided that seventeen individual entry boxes was the right way to go. But, it's tedious to have to tab after each character to get to the next box. Ergo, I'd like to have it so that once I type a character into the first box, it automatically advances to the second. Once I type a character in the second, it automatically advances to the third. And so on. That way I can just type out the VIN.
I'm not having a problem making the boxes, or getting them to function. But I don't yet know Python well enough to know what sort of event function I need to create to get the effect I'm looking for.
I am a newbie. As best as you're able, give me pre-algebra, not calculus, if you catch my drift.
What I've tried working with is this:
def advnum1(event):
    entry = event.widget
    if len(entry.get()) == entry.get_max_length():
        next_widget = entry.tkinter_focusNext()
        if next_widget:
            next_widget.focus()

fnumbox1 = tkinter.Entry(master=cstinfofrmfg, justify="center", bg="#b2b4b7", fg="#000000", width=4)
fnumbox1.place(x=112, y=181.5)
fnumbox1.bind("<KeyRelease>", advnum1)
fnumbox2 = tkinter.Entry(master=cstinfofrmfg, justify="center", bg="#b2b4b7", fg="#000000", width=4)
fnumbox2.place(x=144, y=181.5)
fnumbox3 = tkinter.Entry(master=cstinfofrmfg, justify="center", bg="#b2b4b7", fg="#000000", width=5)
fnumbox3.place(x=176, y=181.5)

But try as I might to change different parts of the expression, everything gives me an error. The get function doesn't seem to like this arrangement. Other things say there's no attribute. I tried putting in the variable name of the Entry control. I've tried a variety of things. Nothing seems to work. I'm assuming this is just an outline script of sorts. But I'm not sure what should actually be as it is, and what should be substituted with specific variables or widget names.

String parsing is not a big deal and is something you should strive to get comfortable with. I would not design your UI around what's easiest to code; design it around the best user experience. Seventeen separate boxes doesn't seem like an improvement over a simple text box.

@JohnKugelman, I won't disagree with you. I can only say that for the sake of brevity, I didn't list every use to which these seventeen digits will be applied. I do agree that I need to learn parsing. I have already started down that road. But I haven't yet come across adequate information to nail it down. That notwithstanding, the individual boxes, as I envision it, should end up being an identical user experience if the cursor advances as I'm attempting to make it do. Thanks for your input. I will continue to work towards learning to parse. I would still like to know how to do as I inquired.

@JohnKugelman, I learned the parsing. Definitely easier than trying to make all those boxes. After a lot of reflection, the individual boxes would have created other logistical nightmares. Someone else did suggest a way of mitigating some of them. But parsing it was still the stronger way to go. Thanks for your input.

This is how I would implement your idea.
I use the string module for an alphanumeric list.
All Entry widgets are stored in 'entry' list.
Variable 'q' determines the total number of Entry widgets.
I would make sure the User enters text in the correct order.
This is done by disabling all Entry widgets except for the relevant one.
When all data has been entered, collect and display then delete for next input.
Alternatively, collect and store data in dictionary that may have User name as a key.
(I haven't implemented that... but it's a logical direction for code expansion)
import tkinter
from string import ascii_letters, digits

entry, result = [], []
alpha = ascii_letters + digits
# place at x, y, width, quantity
x, y, w, q = 10, 20, 20, 16

app = tkinter.Tk()
app.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
app.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

frame = tkinter.Frame(app, width = w*q+w//2, height = y*3)
frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

def select(i):
    entry[i]["state"] = "normal"
    entry[i].delete(0, 'end')
    entry[i].focus_set()

def respond(event):
    global i
    value = entry[i].get()
    if value in alpha and len(value) == 1:
        result.append(value)
        k = i
        i = (i+1)%q
        if i == 0:
            for fun in entry:
                fun["state"] = "normal"
                fun.delete(0, 'end')
                fun["state"] = "disabled"

            print(result)
            result.clear()
        entry[k]["state"] = "disabled"
    select(i)

# Create 'q' entry widgets and store in 'entry' list
for a in range(q):
    entry.append(tkinter.Entry(
        frame, justify="center", bg="#ffffff",
        fg="#000000", show = "*", state = "disabled"))
    entry[a].place(x=x, y=y, width = w//2)
    # Bind every Entry widget
    entry[a].bind("<KeyRelease>", respond)
    x = x + w

# initialize 
i = 0
select(i)
app.mainloop()


I didn't fully understand all of what you wrote there. But I learn fast. It makes sense now. Good answer to the specific question. A commentator on the first post sent me in the direction of just learning to parse it. Ended up being a quick and short piece of code once I learned how to do that. But I gave you an upvote since your answer was good, and right, and on target to the initial question. It actually helped solve a completely unrelated question I had on something else once I understood everything you did there.

Good one @AFrazier. Happy coding.

Okay, I figured it out.
def my_variable(event):
    VINbox1.focus()

This is coupled with:
VINbox1 = tkinter.Entry(master=root, bg="#b2b4b7", fg="#000000", width=1, relief=tkinter.FLAT)
VINbox1.bind("<KeyRelease>", my_variable)

No "if" or "len" tests or comparisons needed to shift focus for a single letter or digit. Although, seventeen individual events will have to be written to do as I was inquiring.
A similar version that I found worked for multiple digits, as in a phone number, was:
def advnum1(event):
    phtext1 = fnumbox1.get()
    phlen1 = len(phtext1)
    if phlen1 == 3:
        fnumbox2.focus()
def advnum2(event):
    phtext2 = fnumbox2.get()
    phlen2 = len(phtext2)
    if phlen2 == 3:
        fnumbox3.focus()
def advnum3(event):
    phtext3 = fnumbox3.get()
    phlen3 = len(phtext3)
    if phlen3 == 4:
        altfnumbox1.focus()

This is combined with:
fnumbox1 = tkinter.Entry(master=cstinfofrmfg, justify="center", bg="#b2b4b7", fg="#000000", width=4)
fnumbox1.place(x=112, y=181.5)
fnumbox1.bind("<KeyRelease>", advnum1)
fnumbox2 = tkinter.Entry(master=cstinfofrmfg, justify="center", bg="#b2b4b7", fg="#000000", width=4)
fnumbox2.place(x=144, y=181.5)
fnumbox2.bind("<KeyRelease>", advnum2)
fnumbox3 = tkinter.Entry(master=cstinfofrmfg, justify="center", bg="#b2b4b7", fg="#000000", width=5)
fnumbox3.place(x=176, y=181.5)
fnumbox3.bind("<KeyRelease>", advnum3)

I'm always open to learning new ways to do things. Any suggestions on a simpler code are welcomed.

What is the reason for using the function more than once? One technique is available to utilize and file a matching state statement. This will assist you in reducing code size.

The "reason" is that I'm still learning the language, so I'm doing it in whatever way I can to accomplish the goal. The code will get cleaner with time. I'm still learning.

@toyotaSupra, any chance you can elaborate? I have three functions because there are three boxes, at least one of which has different criteria for the auto cursor advance. It's for recording a phone number. If there's a simple way to combine all three functions into one, I'm all ears. I have to do the same thing two other times for an alternate phone number, and an alternate contact person phone number. I'm all for simplifying the code.

Try this:
 def advnum(event):
    phtext1 = fnumbox1.get()
    phlen1 = len(phtext1)
    if phlen1 == 3:
        fnumbox2.focus()
        
    phtext2 = fnumbox2.get()
    phlen2 = len(phtext2)
    if phlen2 == 3:
        fnumbox3.focus()


fnumbox1.bind("<KeyRelease>", advnum) and fnumbox2.bind("<KeyRelease>", advnum) and fnumbox3.bind("<KeyRelease>", advnum)

You do not require two additional methods like advnum2 and advnum3.

@toyotaSupra, I was still too new to fully comprehend what you wrote there, but I learn fast. It makes perfect sense now. Thanks for the input and assistance.
